# Permission error on uninstalling matplotlib on Raspberry Pi

Tags: matplotlib, raspberry-pi, uninstallation

I am trying to uninstall version 3.0.2 of matplotlib which came with the NOOBS install on my Raspberry Pi so that I can install a later version. But I ran into permission errors using..

```
python3 -m pip uninstall matplotlib
```

But if I add sudo in front of this command, it comes back saying that there are no files found to uninstall. Below is the screen capture running these 2 commands...

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 -m pip uninstall matplotlib
Uninstalling matplotlib-3.0.2:
  Would remove:
    /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib
    /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib-3.0.2.egg-info
    /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pylab.py
Proceed (y/n)? y
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 563, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/__pycache__/pylab.cpython-37.pyc' -> '/tmp/pip-uninstall-zxmluyqe/pylab.cpython-37.pyc'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 153, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 79, in run
    auto_confirm=options.yes, verbose=self.verbosity > 0,
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 755, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 394, in remove
    moved.stash(path)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 283, in stash
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 338, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 578, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/__pycache__/pylab.cpython-37.pyc'
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python3 -m pip uninstall matplotlib
Not uninstalling matplotlib at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'matplotlib'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to update the package, try:

```
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

or for a specific version:

```
pip install 'matplotlib>=3.1.1' --force-reinstall
```

If you really want to remove it, you can do it manually by getting the address of the package installation with:

```
pip show matplotlib
```

and then manually deleting it with rm -rf.

This error is often caused when installing a package using the "setup.py", or any environment. Both methods don't leave enough metadata for "pip uninstall" to work.

Comment: Additionally, when getting the package adress, you can chech with "ls -lah" who owns the files and also change their permissions accordingly with chmod and chown.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I tried pip show matplotlib and it returned nothing. Then I tried pip install --upgrade matplotlib, it downloaded version 2.2.4 which is much older than the 3.0.2 that came with Raspbian. I needed version 3.1.4 to fix a bug in matplotlib. I rebooted the system and tried pip show matplotlib again. Now it shows version 3.0.2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages.

Comment: I then tried pip install --upgrade matplotlib again. This time it is Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/matplotlib/matplotlib-3.1.2-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl
But when it get to the step of uninstalling matplotlib-3.0.2, it failed with permission error just like I had before.

Comment: I tried rm --rf matplotlib inside the dist-packages folder. But every file failed with permission error. I then tried ls -lah on the matplotlib folder and it listed many files and folders, some with drwxr-xr-x permission and some with -rw-r--r--. I am new to unix. What do I need to do to change these permissions? Kind of confused with the --help from chmod.

Comment: Also, inside the dist-packages folder, there are 2 folders: matplotlib and matplotlib-3.0.2.egg-info. Do I need to remove both of these folders manually? In addition, there is a matplotlib folder in /usr/share and also various files that start with matplotlib in various folders like /etc, /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/plugins/backend etc. Do I need to remove all of them?

Comment: If upgrading is working, you can define the version by: 

pip install 'matplotlib>=3.1.1' --force-reinstall

. I added this to my answer.

Comment: Also, to change permissions, you can try to go to the parent folder and type "chown -R  YOUR_USER matplotlib/". This way you change the ownership of the folder matplotlib and anything inside it to your username. If you just want to delete it, "sudo rm -rf FOLDER" should work.

Comment: I finally just deleted the 2 matplotlib folders with "sudo rm -rf FOLDER" and everything worked. I just was not sure if that is a proper way to uninstall a package. Thanks for the help.